# Pass data between screen when pressed on details inside Listview (flutter_bloc)

Tags: flutter, bloc, gesturedetector

I have Listview and I want to pass the data when I pressed it and show the detail page, this is my listview:

```
 Widget _buildCard(BuildContext context,List<HospitalListModel> model) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: model.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Card(
            child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: (){
                  HospitalDetailPage(
                    title: model[index].title,
                    content: model[index].content,
                    image: model[index].image,
                    phone: model[index].phone,
                    coordinates: model[index].coordinates,
                    website: model[index].website);
                },
                child: Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Image.network(model[index].image),
                  Text("${model[index].title}", style: GoogleFonts.roboto(
                    textStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, letterSpacing: .5, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                  ),),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ));
      },
    );
  }
```

and I made the screen detail, i pass it with `required` on detail page, and i call it on listview page and pass the data

```
HospitalDetailPage({
    Key? key,
    required this.title,
    required this.content,
    required this.image,
    required this.phone,
    required this.coordinates,
    required this.website,
  }) : super(key: key);
```

but somehow it didn't work and when i click the listview, it didn't bring me to detail screen, it stuck in the same screen and im questioning whether im wrong to put the `GestureDetector` or something, do you know where the problem is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't using navigator Try this code...

```
Widget _buildCard(BuildContext context,List<HospitalListModel> model) {
  return ListView.builder(
    itemCount: model.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Card(
          child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: (){
                Navigator.push(context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>  HospitalDetailPage(
                    title: model[index].title,
                    content: model[index].content,
                    image: model[index].image,
                    phone: model[index].phone,
                    coordinates: model[index].coordinates,
                    website: model[index].website)
                  ),
                );
              },
              child: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Image.network(model[index].image),
                Text("${model[index].title}", style: GoogleFonts.roboto(
                  textStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, letterSpacing: .5, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                ),),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ));
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: oh welll so that is the problem, thank you so much to solved my problem